# Como inserir UUID automaticamente em uma coluna MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, auto-incremento, uuid

Existe alguma maneira de se inserir um `UUID` automaticamente em um campo da tabela, da mesma maneira que se faz com um campo do tipo `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Em um *framework* para PHP, o CakePHP, quando definimos a chave primária como `VARCHAR(40)`, ele insere um `UUID` automaticamente, como se fosse o auto incremento da tabela.

Existe uma maneira de fazer isso diretamente pelo MySQL? Ou sempre temos que definir o UUID na hora do `INSERT`?

Exemplo:

```
Usuarios
 - uuid
 - nome
 - senha
```

Comment: Precisa melhorar algo para aceitar?

Comment: @bigown, me falaram que em servidores compartilhadoes, esse `TRIGGER` é bloqueado. Isso procede? Foi por isso que eu não tinha marcado :\

Comment: Até onde eu sei não é não, e se for é caso a caso. Não vejo motivo para ser bloqueado e pela minha experiência, nunca vi ser. E nem é fácil assim bloquear isto, teria que mexer no código do PgSQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Já que o autoincremento precisa de dados constantes estáticos e o UUID teria que ser gerado dinamicamente, acho que a única forma é criando um gatilho, algo assim:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_usuarios
    BEFORE INSERT ON usuarios
    FOR EACH ROW
    SET new.uuid = uuid();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/Trigger.sql).

Comment: Mas isso não alteraria o `uuid` todo insert? Mesmo se o registro já tem um `uuid`?

Comment: Mas se é um `insert` como ele alteraria alguma coisa? Cada linha só terá um `insert`. Depois só é possível fazer `update` na linha.

Comment: Verdade. Erro meu.

Comment: Agora é que isso vai ser útil. Não sei usar trigger, e vou utilizá-la no sistema :)